# File transfer among users with java

Tags: java, network-programming

I am trying to write a code that would enable one user to send to or receive from another user. I have written a method to send file called `sendFile`, it shows that it has sent file but I cannot find where the sent file is saved.

Server side:

```
package DFT;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class ServerSide {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    private static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
    private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2222);
            System.out.println("Distributed File Transfer Server has successfully started");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                    if (threads[i] == null) {
                        (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == maxClientsCount) {
                    PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
                    os.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

class clientThread extends Thread {
    // private DataInputStream is = null;
    private PrintStream os = null;
    private BufferedReader is;
    // private PrintWriter os;
    private Socket clientSocket = null;
    private final clientThread[] threads;
    private int maxClientsCount;
    private String name, pass;
    private int id;
    private static final int totalUser = 5;
    private static final String username[] = new String[totalUser];
    private static final String password[] = new String[totalUser];
    private static boolean online[] = new boolean[totalUser];

    public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] threads) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.threads = threads;

        username[0] = "user1";
        username[1] = "user2";
        username[2] = "user3";
        username[3] = "user4";
        username[4] = "user5";
        password[0] = "123";
        password[1] = "456";
        password[2] = "789";
        password[3] = "012";
        password[4] = "345";

        maxClientsCount = threads.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
        clientThread[] threads = this.threads;

        try {
            /*
             * Create input and output streams for this client.
             */
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            if (is.readLine().trim().equals("login")) {
                name = is.readLine().trim();
                pass = is.readLine().trim();
            }

            int i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < totalUser; i++) {
                if (name.equals(username[i]) && pass.equals(password[i])) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (i < totalUser) {

                if (online[i]) {
                    os.println("This user already logged in");
                    threads[i] = null;
                    is.close();
                    os.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                    return;
                } else {
                    for (j = 0; j < maxClientsCount; j++) {
                        if (threads[j] == this) {
                            threads[j].id = i;
                            online[i] = true;
                        }
                        if (threads[j] != null) {
                            threads[j].os.println("<Server Message>: A new user " + name + " has logged in");
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                os.println("Invalid Username & Password. Terminating");
                for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                    if (threads[i] == this) {

                        threads[i] = null;
                        is.close();
                        os.close();
                        clientSocket.close();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                String line = is.readLine();
                System.out.println("#### " + line);

                if (line.startsWith("logout")) {
                    os.println("Successfully logged out");

                    online[id] = false;

                    for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                        if (threads[i] != null) {
                            if (threads[i] == this)
                                threads[i] = null;
                            else
                                threads[i].os.println("<Server message>: " + name + " has logged out");
                        }
                    }

                    is.close();
                    os.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                    return;
                }

                if (line.startsWith("sendfile ")) {
                    String subline = line.substring(15);
                    String temp = line.substring(9, 14);
                    for (i = 0; i < totalUser; i++) {
                        if (username[i].equals(temp)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (i == totalUser) {
                        os.println("Invalid username");
                        continue;
                    }

                    int k = i;

                    if (!online[k]) {
                        os.println("<Failure>: " + temp + " is not online");
                    } else {
                        os.println("file sent");

                        for (j = 0; j < maxClientsCount; j++) {
                            if (threads[j] != null && threads[j].id == k) {
                                threads[j].os.println("<" + name + "> " + subline);
                            }
                        }
                        sendFile(subline);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (line.startsWith("send ")) {
                    String subline = line.substring(11);
                    String temp = line.substring(5, 10);

                    for (i = 0; i < totalUser; i++) {
                        if (username[i].equals(temp)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (i == totalUser) {
                        os.println("Invalid username");
                        continue;
                    }

                    int k = i;

                    if (!online[k]) {
                        os.println("<Failure>: " + temp + " is not online");
                    }

                    else {
                        os.println("message sent");

                        for (j = 0; j < maxClientsCount; j++) {
                            if (threads[j] != null && threads[j].id == k) {
                                threads[j].os.println("<" + name + ">: " + subline);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void receiveFile() {
        try {
            int bytesRead;
            DataInputStream clientData = null;
            try {
                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                clientData = dataInputStream;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_client_" + fileName));
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                size -= bytesRead;
            }

            output.close();
            clientData.close();

            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " received from client.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.err.println("Client error. Connection closed.");
        }
    }

    public void sendFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            dis.readFully(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
            dos.writeLong(bytearray.length);
            dos.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
            dos.flush();
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " sent to client.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist!");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
package DFT;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ClientSide implements Runnable {
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    private static PrintStream os = null;
    // private static PrintWriter os;
    // private static DataInputStream is = null;
    private static BufferedReader inputLine, is;
    private static boolean closed = false;
    private static String username, password;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2222);
            inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException unknownHostException) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host");
            System.err.print(unknownHostException);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host");
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
            try {

                // Creates a thread to read from the server.
                new Thread(new ClientSide()).start();

                System.out.println("Enter UserName:");
                username = inputLine.readLine().trim();
                System.out.println("Enter Password:");
                password = inputLine.readLine().trim();

                os.println("login");
                os.println(username);
                os.println(password);

                while (!closed) {
                    os.println(inputLine.readLine().trim());
                }

                os.close();
                is.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String responseLine;
        try {
            while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(responseLine);
                if (responseLine.indexOf("*** Bye") != -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            closed = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
        }
    }

    public void receiveFile() {
        try {
            int bytesRead;
            DataInputStream clientData = null;
            try {
                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                clientData = dataInputStream;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_client_" + fileName));
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                size -= bytesRead;
            }

            output.close();
            clientData.close();

            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " received from client.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.err.println("Client error. Connection closed.");
        }
    }

    public void sendFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            dis.readFully(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
            dos.writeLong(bytearray.length);
            dos.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
            dos.flush();
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " sent to client.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist!");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably use more methods in your code. It's hard to see what your code is doing because of all of the catch exceptions, etc. And IOUtils under Apache IO Commons is your friend for dealing with closing streams etc.  If this is just to test some functionality, make all of your methods throw exception to clean up your code a little.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `receiveFile()` method is creating the file, but it is never called in your code.

Comment: receiveFile() was not necessary to send file when I have written code for user to send file to server

Comment: This answer should be a comment.